# How to implement parameterized singleton with Ninject

Tags: c#, singleton, ninject, factory

Is there Ninject based way to implement such a factory:

```
    public class AspectProviderFactory  
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, IAspectProvider> Instances = new Dictionary<string, IAspectProvider>();

    public IAspectProvider Get(string aspectName)
    {
        if (!Instances.ContainsKey(aspectName)) 
            Instances[aspectName] = new AspectProvider(aspectName);
        return Instances[aspectName];
    }
}
```

if I need each singleton instance per each string parameter.

```
Bind<IAspectProvider>().ToConstructor(ctorArg => new AspectProvider(ctorArg.Inject<string>())).InSingletonScope();
```

and

```
var instance1 = Kernel.Get<IAspectParameter>(new ConstructorArgument("aspectName",
                "aspect1");
var instance2 = Kernel.Get<IAspectParameter>(new ConstructorArgument("aspectName",
                "aspect2");
```

doesn't solve the problem, because brings the instance per type instead of per string parameter, so instance1==instance2 here.